# Return the sum of counts from multiple years

Tags: sql, azure

I'm trying to find the 10 year period that produced the most movies. I have a table Called Movie with id, name, and year.

What I've been trying to do is get the count for the number of movies in each year:

```
SELECT year, count(id)
FROM Movie
GROUP BY year
```

Then use that as a subquery to sum every 10 year period and find the max. Is this the right way to do it? Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Any help is appreciated, thank you

EDIT:
Okay I'm able to get a list with each Year and the number of movies made in the next 10 years. Now I'm having trouble only returning the DecadeStart with the max MovieCount. Here's what I have:

```
SELECT m.year AS DecadeStart, (
   SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM Movie m2
   WHERE m2.year >= m.year AND m2.year < (m.year + 10) AND m2.year IS NOT NULL) AS MovieCount
FROM Movie m
GROUP BY m.year);
```

Sample input from Movie table:

```
45|Beach|2008
46|Affair with a Stranger|1953
47|A Letter to Uncle Sam|1913
48|A Woman Scorned|1999
50|Caryl of the Mountains|1914
```

Sample output so far:

```
DecadeStart      MovieCount
1890             3478
1891             4334
1892             5271
```

What I want to do is write a query that will return the year from the row with max MovieCount from this output. So I only want the DecadeStart value back, not the MovieCount

Comment: provide some sample input and output data?..Your question not clear

Comment: Do you want your year grouping as a decade, like `1970s`, `1980s` etc. or do you want it as `1975-1985`, `1993-2003` etc?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Using Azure. A decade grouping can start on any year, so yes 1975 would be valid. I'll edit in sample input and output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
 SELECT DecadeStart, MAX(MovieCount)
     from (
           SELECT m.year AS DecadeStart, (
               SELECT COUNT(*)
               FROM Movie m2
               WHERE m2.year >= m.year AND m2.year < (m.year + 10) 
               AND m2.year IS NOT NULL) 
          as MovieCount
          FROM Movie m GROUP BY m.year
          ) movie ;
```

Comment: When I try that I get an error: "Column 'movie.DecadeStart' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot to add that I only want to return DecadeStart, no MovieCount

Answer (score 0):

If you want the decade-wise, like `1970`, `1980`, etc. data and you are using Oracle, the following will do:

```
SELECT round(year, -1) decade, count(id) cnt
  FROM movies
GROUP BY round(year, -1);
```

If you are using some other RDBMS, try `year%10`.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Azure should support SQL Server's Windowed Aggregate Functions:

```
SELECT TOP 1 
   year as DecadeStart,
   TenYearCnt
FROM
 (
   SELECT year, count(id) as cnt, 
      sum(count(id)) -- moving sum of a 10 years window
      over (order by year
            rows between current row and 9 following) as TenYearCnt
   FROM Movie
   GROUP BY year
 ) AS dt
ORDER BY TenYearCnt DESC
```